# Python: Memory cost of importing a module

Tags: python, memory-efficient

The memory cost obviously depends on exactly how large a module is, but I'm only looking for a general answer: Is it generally expensive or cheap to import a module in Python? If I have a few tens of small scripts that potentially stay in memory for the whole duration of the application, how much will that hog the memory?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it unless you are on an embedded platform or something. Why not try it and see. Most (all?) OS have a way to see how much memory a process is using.

Comment: @gnibbler sure, but they generally aren't very accurate. Memory management in modern OSes involves several layers of smoke and mirrors. But I agree that it's unlikely to matter anyway :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't worried about time cost (good; that would be silly, since modules are only imported once) but memory cost. I put it to you: if you need all the functionality in these modules, then how exactly do you plan to **avoid** having them all in memory? Might as well just `import` things in the most logical way.

That said, in Python `import` is a statement and not some kind of preprocessor directive (or similar), and so you can delay the import of a module until you actually need its contents, by simply arranging for the statement to run at the appropriate time. This can be a meaningful optimization in some particularly large or complex projects, or at least make tricky things possible. Remember, the Python compiler doesn't try to check if there is a `foo` when you refer to `foo.bar`; every name is looked up at run-time. Duck-typing comes into play here; the `foo.bar` code doesn't care whether `foo` is the name of a module, class or object. (That's basically because modules and classes **are** objects, but I digress...)

Comment: This is essentially what the Bazaar DVCS does; you might want to check out the source for it and its "lazy_import" mechanism.