# Correct place to declare many modules providing similar service in javascript

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading, node-modules

I am writing an interface which groups existing node modules providing the same service eg geolocation. App admin can set/choose **only one** module which will provide the service for the entire app.

My questions is: Where should I put the `require` declarations?

a) In the beginning? all declarations together:

```
const _service1 = require('service1');
...
const _serviceN = require('serviceN');
```

or b) Within each own case? One declaration at a time:

```
switch (serviceName) {
    case 'serviceOne':
        const _service1 = require('service1');
        ...
        break;
    ...
    case 'serviceEN':
        const _serviceN = require('serviceN');
        ...
        break;
```

In first case **all** declarations are called **only once**, but in second case **one** declaration is called **each time** the service is requested.

I have thought to use a workaround like:

```
case 'serviceEX':
    if (!_serviceX) {
        const _serviceX = require('serviceX');
    }
    ...
    break;
```

so as declaration takes place only once (when it is called for first time) but I have seen that nowhere else to be used so I do not know if it is practically correct. Please, advise. Tia

Comment: I think the key word here is "**lazy**" (accompanied with "**import**").

Answer (score 0):

According to the Airbnb javascript styleguide you should always do your imports **before** non-imports code.

See [here](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#modules--imports-first) for more information.

Comment: The detail here is that only **one** of 15 modules is finally used. Is there any **memory cost** or any other cost when you put them all of them in the beginning?

Comment: I have found the following post which deals with the same subject/concept but in python's point of view; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812571/python-memory-cost-of-importing-a-module

Comment: Oh, oh, Tim I advise you to **remove** the package name and the reference link because SO employees (paid or unpaid) will close the question as one attracting **opinionated** responses and **advertisements**! They will advise me to ask the question in another site!

Comment: FYI, there are some good packages for lazy modules loading. I do not mention any names because, as explained before, the SO employees will accuse me for advertisement effort.

Answer (score 0):

In js , the most common style of declaring modules is on the start of file.

Comment: I do agree about the common style, but please read my comments in Tim's respond.